# Prevent reuse of custom cells in table view Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

I have a problem which i'm not sure how to solve.

I have two custom cell nibs - data for both is fetched from separate arrays.

The structure is the following

```
nib1-cell line1
nib1-cell line2
...
nib1-cell line n
nib2-cell line1
```

there is always one nib2-cell at the end with the `uibutton`.
Once the `uibutton` is pressed - the nib1 array is appended.
I figured out a way how to insert values at the bottom of the `tableview`, but when i scroll downwards or upwards the cell with nib2 is reused and replaced with nib1-cell data.
[image]

How can i either prevent those cells from being reused or save their state ?

Thank you.

UPDATE: datasource and cellForRowAtIndexPath code

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
    return someTagsArray.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    if(indexPath.row < someTagsArray.count - 1){
        var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell

        cell.lblCarName.text = someTagsArray[indexPath.row]


        return cell

    } else if (indexPath.row == someTagsArray.count - 1){
      var celle:vwAnswers = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! vwAnswers
        celle.Answer1.setTitle(answersdict[answersdict.endIndex - 2], forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        answertitle1 = "\(celle.Answer1.currentTitle!)"

        celle.Answer2.setTitle(answersdict.last, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        answertitle2 = "\(celle.Answer2.currentTitle!)"

        //println(answertitle2)

        return celle

    } else {
                    var cell2:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell
        return cell2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to determine which type of cell you want in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and dequeue the correct reusable cell. Maybe something like `if (indexPath.row + 1)%3 == 0` then dequeue an answer cell.

However, you may possibly want to look in to using a section header for this instead. Hard to say without seeing how you implement your data source.

Comment: the issue with `if (indexPath.row + 1)%3 == 0` is that the second nib shouldn't always be the third in row, it might be fifth, sixth - because the amount of objects in the array for the first nib varies. i have also added the code in my post for the datasource.

Comment: You should just think about what data you need and how you want to access it. You either need to keep track of how many question cells you have each time and use that to place the answer cell, or separate it into multiple arrays. I would suggest possibly using an array of arrays `[Array<String>]` so each array in the data source represents a list of questions.